# How to view the triggers for "ask to send notifications"

Tags: google-chrome, browser, push-notification, notifications, settings

On my website, first-time visitors keep being prompted to configure their notification settings. Below is an image (not mine specifically, but similar case) that illustrates the modal I'm referencing.

[*An example of the "ask to send notifications" modal.*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UBbk1.png)

I'm aiming to remove whatever packages / services are causing this modal to appear. **Is there any way to view what's triggering the "ask to send notifications" modal**?

Note that I'm asking from the developer perspective, ***not*** a user fiddling with their own browser notification settings. Ideally, I can change the code so that the user isn't prompted to adjust their browser notification settings in the first place.

Also, to narrow the scope, primarily concerned with the Google Chrome browser for starters.